# Replace all the matches in a string that matches array values

Tags: php, arrays, regex, replace

I have a string that I am checking for matches using my array and if there are any matches I want to replace those matches with the same words, but just styled red and then return all the string with the colored words included in one piece. This is what I have tried:

```
$string = 'This is a brovn fox wit legs.';
$misspelledOnes = array('wit', 'brovn');

  echo '<p>' . str_replace($misspelledOnes,"<span style='color:red'>". $misspelledOnes  . "</span>". '</p>', $string;
```

But of course this doesn't work, because the second parameter of `str_replace()` can't be an array.  How to overcome this?

Comment: It also won't work because it's not even valid PHP. I suggest you just loop over the array running `str_replace()` for each word. Regular expressions would be more efficient, but not something you want to get into at this stage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most basic approach would be a [`foreach` loop](http://php.net/foreach) over the check words:

```
$string = 'This is a brovn fox wit legs.';
$misspelledOnes = array('wit', 'brovn');

foreach ($misspelledOnes as $check) {
    $string = str_replace($check, "<span style='color:red'>$check</span>", $string);
}
echo "<p>$string</p>";
```

Note that this does a simple substring search. For example, if you spelled "with" properly, it would still get caught by this. Once you get a bit more familiar with PHP, you could look at something using [regular expressions](http://php.net/preg-replace) which can get around this problem:

```
$string = 'This is a brovn fox wit legs.';
$misspelledOnes = array('wit', 'brovn');
$check = implode("|", $misspelledOnes);
$string = preg_replace("/\b($check)\b/", "<span style='color:red'>$1</span>", $string);
echo "<p>$string</p>";
```

Comment: OK, your first suggestion returns the string with only one word('wit') colored red, I need that all the values from the array that matches would be colored - that means 'brovn' should be colored as well in the final result/string .

Comment: Oh, now adjusted it correctly - my bad. Your solution really works ! Thanks!